# Loop multiple sums mysql

Tags: mysql

For a reporting tool im building I would like to be able to count how many "events" happened in each country that has been recorded so far I have this query:

```
SELECT 'country',
      COUNT(*) AS total,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `country` = 'USA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS USCount,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `country` = 'Canada' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CanadaCount
  FROM events WHERE `date` > '2015-06-01' AND `date` < '2015-08-01'
```

The only problem with this is that the cases will start to get enormous when I start adding other countries into the mix. Is there a way I can loop over country to retrieve all of the various counts for each country? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group it by the country name to get the count country wise

```
SELECT country,
  COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM events WHERE `date` > '2015-06-01' AND `date` < '2015-08-01' group by country;
```

Comment: Welcome Chad Watkins :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following SQL statement:

```
Select country, count (*)
From events
Group by country
```